# JQuery - Datatable search using dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a datatable where I have date fields. Since I am in Australia, I have set the date format to dd/mm/yyyy using the date-uk.js which does the formatting just fine.

However, when I go to the search field and type in a date using the dd/mm/yyyy, it does not give the right results. I have to enter the date in yyyy-mm-dd format to get the correct information.

Is there a way I can modify the search to correctly search when I enter a date in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add the data the way you want it to be searchable into your td :

```
<td data-search="24/01/2016">24/01/2016</td>
```

to be sure the search will look for the data the way you want...
[(reference here)](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)

Comment: I'll go through this more thoroughly but not sure how I go about formatting this since the info is retrieved through a database.